# Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
INSERT INTO companies(company_code, company_title, group_id, created_by, 
created_at, updated_at, deleted_at) 
VALUES('2','"pkgs','1','test',NOW(),NOW(),'');
```

## 1062 - Duplicate entry '2' for key 'company_code'

Comment: It seems you have `company_code` as primary key. Check 2 is already there in 
 the table `select company_code from companies`

Comment: is company_code primary key?

Comment: yes it is primary

Comment: 2 company code is already present in the database. Provide other company code that is not present in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @company_code as varchar(10) = '2'

INSERT INTO companies(company_code, company_title, group_id, created_by, 
created_at, updated_at, deleted_at) 
select @company_code,'"pkgs','1','test',NOW(),NOW(),'' where not exists(Select 1 from companies where company_code = @company_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your company_code is primary key and data with company_code = 2 is already present in db, so whenever you try to run this query, it will throw error of duplication. Either run update query to update values or delete this row and insert new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert duplicate entries to a `PRIMARY KEY` column. If you want to use same `company_code` in multiple rows, then you need to change the `PRIMARY KEY`. If you want to use this column value as like an id, then you can implement `AUTO_INCREMENT` (`IDENTITY` in MS SQL Server) and this will set the column values automatically and increment in each row. No need to pass this value through the script.

```
CREATE TABLE companies (
    company_code int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ...................
    ...................
    PRIMARY KEY (company_code)
);
```

Then you can insert the values like,

```
INSERT INTO companies(company_title, group_id, created_by, 
created_at, updated_at, deleted_at) 
VALUES('"pkgs','1','test',NOW(),NOW(),'');
```